# Як перекласти українською «rebate» у контексті «інструмент стимулювання продажів»?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Як перекласти українською «rebate» у контексті «інструмент стимулювання продажів»: «повернення покупцю частини вартості товару (послуги) після пред'явлення доказу покупки товару чи послуги (як правило, вище якогось встановленого порогу)»?
На Вікіпедії: [rebate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebate_(marketing)).

На Вікіпедії існує ця ж стаття російською (український варіант, на жаль, не існує), де основим варіантом дають кальку з англійської: [раба́т, реба́т, ребе́йт, рибе́йт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82_(%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

В статті також пропонують **ретро-бонус**. Цей варіант мені більше подобається, ніж шаблонний переклад Google Перекладача ([знижка, поступка, уступка](https://translate.google.com/#en/uk/rebate)), бо у мене знижка асоціюється з моментом продажу, а в цьому випадку rebate найчастіше виплачується набагато пізніше моменту покупки, тому ця знижке є пост-фактум (або ретро).

Який варіант є найвживанішим в українській діловій мові?

Які (повні) словники існують з термінологією, що стосується маркетингу та фінансів? Спробував шукати через гугл але ті словники, що я знайшов, не містять саме цей термін.

Comment: Можливо "відшкодування"?

Comment: @Tsumiman здається, в цьому випадку необхідно коротко передати ідею відтермінованої вигоди

Comment: @Chizh Так, саме про це й йдеться. Вигода відтермінована.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В українській діловій мові є термін "Рабат" (якщо не брати до уваги термін "знижка, бонус").
Так, цей термін зустрічається в наступних виданнях:

**[Тритомник «Економічна енциклопедія», 2000-2002](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F)**

РАБАТ [РАБАТ]

*1. Знижка з тарифу, яку надають компанії-перевізники вантажовідправникам за використання ними для перевезення своїх вантажів виключно суден цієї компанії. Застосовують два типи знижок: контрактнії вистрочені. 2. Знижка з ціни за умови, що товари від-правляються великими партіями.* [(лінк)](http://studentbooks.com.ua/content/view/54/1/1/1/#4755)

**Українська Радянська Енциклопедія**

*(нім. Rabatt, від франц. rabattre — знижувати) — комерційна знижка з усієї суми грошей, що належить за товар. Надається при сплачуванні готівкою, закупівлі товару оптом тощо.*

[**Юридична енциклопедія - Шемшученко Ю. С.**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F_(%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F))

(нім.—знижка, від франц. — робити поступку, збавляти) — 1) В торг, мореплавстві — знижка з тарифу, яку компанія-перевізник надає вантажовідправнику за перевезення його вантажів суднами компанії. На практиці використовуються два осн. типи Р.: контрактні (заздалегідь передбачені у відповід. угоді сторін) і відстрочені (надаються після неодноразових мор. перевезень). Розмір, порядок і умови їх застосування визначаються відповід. нормами зак-ва про торгове мореплавство, а також конкр. договорами (контрактами) у сфері мор. перевезень (див. Договір морського перевезення вантажу). 2) Знижка на договір, засадах з ціни за умови, що товари відправляються (купуються) великими партіями. Встановлюється у договорі купівлі-продажу за угодою сторін і має на меті стимулювати покупця до придбання великих
партій товару.

**Загородній А. Г., Вознюк Г. Л. Фінансово-економічний словник**

Рабат - (нім., від франц. — знижувати) - 1) зниження продавцем ціни товару в разі закупівлі його великими партіями. Звичайно Р. надають як певну суму чи відсоток від вартості товару;
2) зниження ціни, яке брокер надає страхувальникові, зменшуючи свої комісійні (брокерські).

---

> *«Другий та третій види програм нарахування знижок та бонусів – за програмами відшкодування та за програмами бонусів – ще не так давно
>   практично не використовувалися у вітчизняній практиці, але набули
>   надзвичайної популярності в зарубіжних країнах. У різних країнах та
>   джерелах **знижки** та **бонуси** за програмами відшкодування
>   називаються по-різному: **ретро- знижки, знижки сконто, рібейт,
>   премія** тощо. Але незалежно від назви головною відмінністю бонусів і
>   знижок, наданих у межах другого та третього виду програм, від знижок
>   за першим видом програм є час надання знижки: якщо в рамках дисконтних
>   програм знижки надаються покупцеві в момент продажу, то в межах
>   програм відшкодування та бонусних програм покупець отримує бонуси
>   згодом – у разі наперед обумовленого часу чи форми оплати, досягнення
>   певного обсягу покупок, здійснення покупцем інших дій, настання певних
>   умов тощо».*
>
> [PDF, Дисертація на здобуття наукового ступеня кандидата економічних наук, ст. 76](http://nasoa.edu.ua/wp-content/uploads/zah/amalian_dis.pdf)

Comment: +1: Це те, що я називаю — якісна відповідь у стилі StackExchange.

Comment: +1: Повністю згоден. Вичерпна відповідь. Дуже дякую. Мені найбільше подобається варіант "ретро-знижка" або "ретро-бонус".